# Isomorphism problem among Thompson's groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

I am looking for a reference proving the following statement:

> For every $n,m \geq 2$, the groups $T_n$ and $T_m$ are isomorphic if and only if $n=m$.

Here, $T_k$ denotes the variation of Thompson's group $T$ (compared to $F$, $T$ acts on the circle instead of the interval) where dyadic numbers are replaced with $k$-adic numbers.

I do not focus only on the first appearance of this statement. If several proofs are available in the literature, I am also interested to know them.

Comment: The notion of $k$-adic is not that clear for $k$ not prime (understanding $\mathbf{Z}[1/2]$ as "dyadic numbers", one might view $1/2$ as invertible $4$-adic and $2/3$ as invertible $6$-adic but you probably don't want slope $2/3$ in $T_6$ or slope $1/2$ in $T_4$). Do you mean that breakpoints are in $\mathbf{Z}[1/k]$ and slopes are in the multiplicative group $\langle k\rangle$?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1989-312-02/S0002-9947-1989-0988881-4/S0002-9947-1989-0988881-4.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiM-Kny7JnmAhXHct8KHS-PBgYQFjAAegQIBRAC&usg=AOvVaw2kkmHD3UM355J3g4IoJIWW

Comment: Mark links to: *M. Rubin, Trans. AMS 1989 "On the reconstruction..."* [at AMS site](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1989-312-02/S0002-9947-1989-0988881-4/S0002-9947-1989-0988881-4.pdf)

Comment: BTW, the right generality for such groups was found by Higman (1974): consider $T_{n,k}$ for some $k\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$, namely the group of piecewise affine self-homeomorphisms of $\mathbf{R}/k\mathbf{Z}$, affine outside $\mathbf{Z}[1/n]/k\mathbf{Z}$ and slopes in $n^\mathbf{Z}$. The simplistic restriction to $k=1$ by subsequent authors leads to a mistaken generality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I can tell, a solution to this problem has not appeared in the literature. Unless I'm mistaken, the best partial result was obtained by Liousse in [this 2008 paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10711-007-9216-y), where it is proven by examining possible orders of elements that $T_m$ is not isomorphic to $T_n$ if there exists a prime that divides $m-1$ but not $n-1$.

However, as Mark indicates it is possible to use Rubin's work to solve this problem.  I will use the theorem of Rubin that appears in the following paper:

[M. Rubin, Locally moving groups and reconstruction problems. *Ordered groups and infinite permutation groups.* Springer, Boston, MA, 1996. 121-157.](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4613-3443-9_5)

The theorem can be stated as follows.  Let $G$ be a group acting faithfully by homeomorphisms on a topological space $X$. We say that the action of $G$ on $X$ is a ***Rubin action*** if the following conditions are satified:

1. $X$ is locally compact and Hausdorff, and has no isolated points.
2. For every non-empty open set $U\subseteq X$ and every point $p\in U$, the closure of the set
   $$
   \{g(p) \mid g\in G\text{ and $g$ is supported on $U$}\}
   $$
   has nonempty interior.

Rubin refers to condition (2) by saying that the action of $G$ on $X$ is "locally moving".  Rubin's theorem is the following.

> **Theorem (Rubin).** Let $G$ and $H$ be groups acting faithfully by homeomorphisms on spaces $X$ and $Y$, respectively, and let $\varphi\colon G\to H$ be an isomorphism.  If both actions are Rubin actions, then there exists a homeomorphism $h\colon X\to Y$ such that $\varphi(g)=hgh^{-1}$ for all $g\in G$.

Now, it is easy to check that the action of $T_m$ on the circle $S^1 = [0,1]/\{0,1\}$ is Rubin.  Thus $T_m$ and $T_n$ are isomorphic if and only if there exists a homeomorphism $h\colon S^1\to S^1$ such that $T_m=hT_nh^{-1}$.

Thus we can distinguish $T_m$ and $T_n$ if we can find any property distinguishing them that is invariant under conjugation by a homeomorphism.  One useful conjugacy invariant  was used by Bleak and Lanoue in the following paper to prove non-isomorphism for Brin's higher-dimensional Thompson groups $nV$.:

[C. Bleak and D. Lanoue, A family of non-isomorphism results. *Geometriae Dedicata* **146.1** (2010): 21-26.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10711-009-9423-9)

Bleak and Lanoue use the following technique.  Given a group $G$ of homeomorphisms of a space $X$, let $(g)_p$ denote the [germ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germ_(mathematics)) of an element $g\in G$ at a point $p\in X$, and let
$$
(G)_p = \{(g)_p \mid g\in G\text{ and }g(p)=p\}.
$$
Note that composition of germs induces a group structure on $(G)_p$.  This is the ***group of germs*** for $G$ at $p$.  If $h\colon X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism, it is easy to prove that the mapping
$$
(g)_p \mapsto (hgh^{-1})_{h(p)}
$$
is an isomorphism $(G)_p\to (hGh^{-1})_{h(p)}$, i.e. the isomorphism type of $(G)_p$ is invariant under conjugation by a homeomorphism.  Bleak and Lanoue prove that $mV$ and $nV$ are non-isomorphic for $m\ne n$ by proving that the isomorphism types of the groups of germs are different.

Now let $T_m$ act on the circle $S^1 = [0,1]/\{0,1\}$.  If $p\in S^1$, it is easy to check that the groups of germs for $T_m$ at $p$ has the following isomorphism type:
$$
(T_m)_p \cong \begin{cases}\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} & \text{if }p\text{ is }m\text{-adic} \\ \mathbb{Z} & \text{if }p\text{ is rational but not }m\text{-adic} \\ 1 & \text{if }p\text{ is irrational}.\end{cases}
$$
Since the possible isomorphism types here do not depend on $m$, we cannot use Bleak and Lanoue's method directly.  However, it follows from the above considerations that any homeomorphism $h\colon S^1\to S^1$ conjugating $T_m$ to $T_n$ must map the set of $m$-adic points in $S^1$ to the set of $n$-adic points in $S^1$.

Thus it suffices to prove that the dynamics of the action of $T_m$ on the $m$-adic points is somehow different from the dynamics of the action of $T_n$ on the $n$-adic points.  This is actually quite easy: it is well-known that the group $T_m$ has exactly $m-1$ orbits on the set of ordered pairs $(x_1,x_2)$ of distinct $m$-adics in $S^1$.  Specifically, if we write
$$
x_1 = \frac{i}{m^k}\qquad\text{and}\qquad x_2=\frac{j}{m^k}
$$
for $0\leq i<m^k$ and $i<j< i+m^k$ (so $x_2$ is represented by a point in the interval $(x_1,x_1+1)$), then the orbit of $(x_1,x_2)$ is determined by the value of $j-i$ modulo $m-1$.  It follows that no homeomorphism can conjugate $T_m$ to $T_n$ for $m\ne n$, so by Rubin's theorem these groups are not isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add a small comment to Jim Belk's detailed and clear answer.

There is a preprint [Xiaobing Sheng's work describing quasi-isometric embeddings from $T_n$ to $T$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00866) which also provides a partial answer along the lines of Liousse's paper mentioned in J. Belk's answer.  I am not certain of the current publication status of Sheng's paper.  The relevant proposition there is:

Proposition 3.1.2. The order of a torsion element in $T_n$ is a divisor of $l(n − 1) + 1$
for some integer $l \geq 0$.

Comment: Indeed.  I believe [Feyishayo Olukoya's recent preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03816) on automorphisms of the $T_n$'s may also be relevant.  Brin proved that $\mathrm{Out}(T_2)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, and Olukoya proves that $\mathrm{Out}(T_m)$ is infinite for $m\geq 3$, which gives an independent proof that $T_2$ is not isomorphic to $T_m$ for $m\geq 3$.